# Three.js Line Using Orthographic Camera

Tags: three.js, line, mesh, orthographic

I am using `THREE.MeshLine` from https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine to try and draw lines in three.js. The lines appear to work when using a perspective camera to view the scene as the demos showed, but when I use an orthographic camera which is the camera I need to use for my project, the line is distorted.

For now, I am trying to make sure that the line works by creating a sin wave, but with the ortho camera, it looks like this:

[image]

Why does the mesh not display correctly with an orthographic camera? Are there any ways to fix this or achieve orthographic lines with a thickness in three.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue, see https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine/issues/118.

The [wide line implementation](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat) of `three.js` does support orthographic cameras, though.